# PHP submission form

Tags: php, sql, submission

I'm making a simple submission form using PHP but I'm getting this error...

> Undefined index: username in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\wamp\www\alternate\upload.php

I have two small php files one for connecting to my database and another to handle the submission(not fully done).

**connect.php**

```
<?php 
$error="unable to connect.";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die($error);
mysql_select_db("test") or die ($error);

session_start();
?>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$_SESSION['username']=='registeredUser';

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<p>";

echo "Upload your image:

<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value ='upload'>
</form>

";

?>
```

At this point I should be able to see the form with the name of the registered user but I'm being told that the column where I'm looking for that name in doesn't exist. My database is setup with table and the user accounted for.

Comment: Do you mean `$_SESSION['username']='registeredUser';`?

Comment: `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment. `$_SESSION['username']=='registeredUser';` isn't doing what you think it should.

Answer (score 3):

You used double equals in you answer you need a single equals

```
$_SESSION['username']=='registeredUser';
//change to
$_SESSION['username']='registeredUser';
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I did that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need a single equals and use `<?php session_start(); ?>` in header.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$_SESSION['username']=='registeredUser';` to set a session variable. The `==` operator is the loosely-typed comparison operator, not the assignment operator. To assign a value to a variable, use a single `=` sign, like-so: `$_SESSION['username']='registeredUser';`